# UL won't center on the Div. Padding won't fix it. Margin either

Tags: html, css, html-lists, center, padding

I see this question a lot but I can't find the answer with either padding or margin. For some reason I can't center the `ul` element correctly inside the `div` and the `div` needs to be this way.

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and how to solve it?

https://jsfiddle.net/norbertoalexander/4ea23bbn/2/

```css
/* FUENTES
font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
*/

/*
Fondo = #FEFFA0
Borde = #ACDB86
Fondo Texto = #EEEEEE
Hoover = #547C66
Letras = #3B5B5D
*/

html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #FEFFA0;
}

div.head {
 height: 70px;
 background-color: #ACDB86;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
 font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
 font-size: 45px;
 text-align: center;
}

div.menu {
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: blue;
 margin: 5px;
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 height: 500px;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
}

ul {
 margin: 0 auto;
 list-style: none;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
}

li {
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}

h2 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}

div.fuent {
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: blue;
 margin: 5px;
 float: right;
 width: 150px;
 height: 500px;
}

div.leng {
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: yellow;
 margin: 5px;
 width: 72%;
 float: left;
}

div.resu {
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: blue;
 margin: 5px;
 width: 72%;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML">
<html>
<head>
<title>Lenguajes</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="styles/leng.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <!--titulo-->
 <div class="head">
 <h1>Lenguajes</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><h2>Menu</h2></li>
   <li><a href="index.html">Incio</a></li>
   <li><a href="algoritmo.html">Algoritmos</a></li>
   <li><a href="lenguajes.html">Lenguajes</a></li>
   <li><a href="problemas.html">Problemas</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">Sobre mi</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="fuent">
 Fuentes
 </div>
 <div class="resu">
 Resumen
 </div>
 <div class="leng">
 Lenguaje
 </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: you want centering the ul according to which (div or window) ? Please be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a padding on the `<ul>`, remove it and the menu is centered:

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```